# A convergence in sobolev spaces involving time

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Suppose $\Omega $ is bounded and

$$‎‎u^m‎‎\xrightarrow[]{w^*}‎ u ‎\quad \text{in} \,\, ‎L^{\infty} ‎(‎\mathbb{R}^+,H^2(‎\Omega‎)‎\cap ‎H_0^1(‎\Omega‎))$$

and

‎$$‎‎u^m_t\xrightarrow[]{w^*}‎ u_t ‎\quad \text{in} \,\,‎L^\infty ‎(‎\mathbb{R}^+,L^2(‎\Omega‎)‎)\cap ‎L^2 ‎(‎\mathbb{R}^+,‎H_0^1(‎\Omega‎))$$

I want to prove

‎‎‎‎$$u^m‎‎\xrightarrow[]{strongly}‎ u ‎\quad ‎\text{in} \,\,L^2 ‎(‎(0,T),‎H_0^1(‎\Omega‎))$$

It is used in some papers and non of them have a proof. I know it comes from Aubin-Lions Lemma but the most general lemma I found doesn't work. The lemma works If we show:

$$‎‎‎‎u^m‎‎\xrightarrow[]{w^*}‎ u ‎\quad ‎\text{in} \,\,L^2 ‎(‎(0,T),H^2(‎\Omega‎)‎\cap ‎H_0^1(‎\Omega‎))$$

But how? I will be thankful for any hint.

Comment: Why do you mix $L^p(0,T;\ldots)$ and $L^p(\mathbb{R}^+;\ldots)$??

Comment: I didn't :) this is from a paper and maybe it is essential. If you can prove it any way with any assumption please write it down. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have $u^m \to u$ weak-* in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^+; H_0^1(\Omega))$. Hence, $u^m \to u$ weak-* in $L^\infty(0,T; H_0^1(\Omega))$. And this gives $u^m \to u$ weak in $L^2(0,T; H_0^1(\Omega))$. No need for Aubin-Lions here.

Comment: OMG :) how fool I am and how simple it was. thanks.

Comment: @A.F.23, gerw I'd say that $u^m \overset{w^*}\longrightarrow u$ in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^+; H_0^1(\Omega))$ implies $u^m \overset{w^*}\longrightarrow u$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^+; H_0^1(\Omega))$ which implies $u^m \overset{w^*}\longrightarrow u$ in $L^2(0,T; H_0^1(\Omega))$. Here we pass from $L^2(\mathbb{R}^+; H_0^1(\Omega))$ to $L^2(0,T; H_0^1(\Omega))$ because $u\mapsto u|_{(0,T)}$ is continuous and, in these $L^2$ spaces, the weak and weak-$*$ topologies coincide. But in the argumment  of the answer, how to pass from $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^+; H_0^1(\Omega))$ to $L^\infty(0,T; H_0^1(\Omega))$?

Comment: These are the dual spaces of $L^1(\mathbb{R}^+; H^{-1}(\Omega))$ and $L^1(0,T;H^{-1}(\Omega))$. Moreover, $L^1(0,T;H^{-1}(\Omega))\subset L^1(\mathbb{R}^+; H^{-1}(\Omega))$. So weak-* in $L^\infty(0,T; H_0^1(\Omega))$ amounts to testing with a function $v \in L^1(0,T;H_0^1(\Omega))$, which belongs to $L^1(\mathbb{R}^+;H_0^1(\Omega))$. Hence, $\langle u^m, v\rangle$ converges.

Comment: @gerw Ok, we have $u_n\to u$ weak-* in $L^\infty(\mathbb R^+;H_0^1)$ which means $\int_\mathbb{R^+}\langle v(s),u_n(s)\rangle \to \int_\mathbb{R^+}\langle v(s),u(s)\rangle $ for all $v\in L^1(\mathbb R^+;H^{-1})$. So, for $v\in L^1(0,T;H^{-1})$ we have $\int_\mathbb{R^+}\langle v(s),u_n(s)\rangle\to \int_\mathbb{R^+}\langle v(s),u(s)\rangle$ because $v\in L^1(0,T;H^{-1})\subset L^1(\mathbb{R}^+;H^{-1})$ as you said (extending with zero outside $[0,T]$). But to get $u_n\to u$ weak-* in $L^\infty(\mathbb 0,T;H_0^1)$ we need replace the last two $\int_{\mathbb R^+}$ by $\int_0^T$. How to do this?

Comment: This can be done since $v \in L^1(0,T;H^{-1})$ vanishes outside $[0,T]$.

Comment: I was edited my question guys. I wanted to prove convergence strongly, anyway gerw argument works to show last convergence in question and that helps me to use Aubin-Lions lemma. I will edit your solution if you agree.

Comment: @A.F.23: Feel free to edit my answer accordingly.